# show / hide DOM elements in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have something very simple but I can not make it work correctly in Webkit and Mozilla

This is my HTML

```
<li style="padding-bottom: 10px;" class='product'>
  <span class ='handle' style="cursor:move; float:left; margin-top:40px; margin-right:8px; margin-bottom:30px; display:none;">
          <%= image_tag "page/arrow.png"%>
  </span>

<table >
    <tr style="border:5px; solid: #444">
      <td class="product_contents" style="vertical-align: top;" >
        <div class="product_contents" style="width: 480px; font-size: 100%; font-weight: bold; color: #333; margin-bottom: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto;">
         STUFF HERE
        </div>
        <p class="product_contents" style="width: 480px; font-size: 93%; line-height: 150%; word-wrap: break-word; overflow: auto;">
      MORE STUFF HERE
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</li>
```

And this is my JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".product").mouseenter(
    function () { 
      $(this).find(".handle").css('display', 'inline'); //show();
      $(this).css('background-color','#fffdef');
      $(this).find(".product_contents").css('width', '450px');
  });
  $(".product").mouseleave(
    function () {
      $(this).find(".handle").css('display', 'none'); //.hide();
      $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
      $(this).find(".product_contents").css('width', '480px');
  });
  });
```

Nothing fancy here at all and it works as I expect in Firefox. The image in handle appears on the left and it displaces the content to the right, the content also change colors and size to match the image. PErfect.
But in Webkit it changes the color and the size but there is no displacement. What I want to achieve is pretty basic, there is a better approach? 
I can use Jquery but I can not use any plugin.

Comment: This works for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/TkKYc/.

Comment: This would likely be far more efficient if a class was added to the subject elements and the class's style rule was modified. If you must use a selector, at least get the object once and re-use it: `var el = $(this); el.find(...); el.css(...);` and so on.

Comment: it does not work for me in Chrome. I have tried your fiddle and the "image" appears over the text. If you try with firefox the same fiddle you will see how it appears at the left side. Quite different

Comment: As per my testing, [this particular fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkKYc/) works the same way in Firefox 4, Chrome, IE9, and Opera. In Safari it appears on the left. Then again I haven't tried with an actual image. And what do you mean by "...not work correctly in Mozilla..." <==> "...it works as I expect in Firefox..."?

Comment: If I wrote "not correctly in mozilla" I meant correctly with mozilla. Firefox is working Ok, I have issues with chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem right, but I would recommend to try jQuery's show/hide functions:

```
$(this).find(".handle").show();
$(this).find(".handle").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide an element by using the CSS *display* property and setting it to *none*.

```
$("element").style.display = "none"; // hide element

$("element").style.display = "block"; // show element (or inline)
```

Comment: Actually, in jQuery it would rather be something like `$(...).get(0).style`.

Comment: In addition, for your code to work, you'd need two variables named `none` and `block` containing strings with the content equal to the name of the corresponding variable it was placed in... or you could just use `"none"` and `"block"` instead of `none` and `block`.

Comment: sorry about that. I just forgot the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me in Firefox, and fails for Conkeror (which was surprising), and fails for SRWare Iron (which is a Chrome-based browser).

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the table is inside a `<li>` element. For some reason, Firefox treats this table as an inline element, and the other browsers as a block element. Since it is a block element, the table is pushed to the next line, and is not displaced, because the handle is on the previous line. Changing the display style of the table to `inline-table` fixed the issue for me.